Should I add "the" at the beginning of this title: "Job market in Poland" and why/why not?
It's a title of a market report on availability of jobs, salaries, etc. in Poland.

It's optional. Do you have any other reports with similar titles you can copy?

Thanks!
I do have some other reports, but they were also translated from Polish and I wasn't sure the translations are correct.
Plus, there's an additional word in the other ones, e.g., "The IT Job Market in Poland".

Titles often omit articles for brevity. But if it doesn't make the title too long, using "the" sounds better.

The Job Market in Poland [for a formal title], We would use the here in journalese or academic writing.

You have a choice either to use "the" or omit it (zero article).
I saw in the comments that you have a specific report on the IT industry.
"The IT Job Market in Poland".
In case of titles it is not incorrect to write or omit "the".
For the report on all the industries you can use "Job market in Poland"

Could whoever down-voted that wholly correct Answer justify the vote, or just retract it, please?
If anyone else doubts James Mathai's Answer, Edited or not, can that one say why?
